# Can you use a standard set controller on a javascript button?

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have a javascript button that pops out a new window showing a vf page.

[image]

the code

```
function popitup(url) { 
var newwindow = window.open(url,'','height=300,width=600', opener='/'); 

if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()} 
return false; 
} 

// place the standardSetController logic here
popitup('/apex/VisualForcePageThatUsesStandardSetController');
```

Is there a way to place the logc for the standard set controller in the code above?

When I configure the button this way

[image]

it places this code at the end of the url.

/apex/VisualForcePageThatUsesStandardSetController +

> ?retURL=%2F00Q%3Ffcf%3D00B41000003B4qV&wrapMassAction=1&scontrolCaching=1

My requirement. Instead of loading to a different vf page when clicking my "Send Mass Survey" button, I want to stay on this page

[image]

and load a new window that goes to my vf page with the selected Leads.

Comment: what's the purpose of putting standardSetController logic in javascript? what's your exact use case?

Comment: @SantanuBoral cause I'm using a list button. I want a popup window to display the vf page.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement, you want to pass selected LeadIds to visualforce page.

So, take this approach.

**Code behind Javascript Button**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 

var selectedIds = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead)}; //chosen records from list view checkboxes

window.open('/apex/leadSurveyPage?selectedLeadIds=' + selectedIds, '_blank');
```

All the selectedIds to be passed as parameter and VFP Controller's constructor will capture from URL parameters.

**Visualforce**

Just to show selected Ids

```
<apex:page controller="LeadSurveyController">

      <apex:repeat value="{!selectedLeadIds}" var="str">
          {!str} <br/>

      </apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class LeadSurveyController
{

    public List<String> selectedLeadIds {get;set;}

    public LeadSurveyController()
    {
        String str = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedLeadIds');
        if(str !=null)
        {
            selectedLeadIds = String.escapeSingleQuotes(str).split(',');
        }

        //now, you have the expected Ids, you can use it in SOQL
    }
}
```

Comment: What code do I put in my javascript code so it loads the right records when using a js button?

Comment: whats your exact requirement? I think you have a list button and you want to display a visualforce page where you want to work with multiple records, correct?

Comment: correct, but I want the vf page to load in a new window, that pops up

Comment: do you want selected records to be passed to VFP?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: How does that use the standard set controller though? When I use your code it looks like it just puts the record ids in the url.

Comment: can you update your question and put the actual use case? it seems like bit and pieces are there. Probably I could guide you simple way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61188/discussion-between-tyler-zika-and-santanu-boral).

Comment: updated my answer which you are looking for

Comment: did my answer solves your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Santanu describe it correctly.

```
window.open('/apex/leadSurveyPage?selectedLeadIds=' + selectedIds, '_blank');
```

Here **window.open** will open up the VF page in a new window with the selected Lead IDs.